# Configuring Network interfaces

Tags: networking, vmware

I'm having a problem bringing up eth1 and eth0 on my VMware running Ubuntu 12.04
I have 2bridges and 1NAT and heres my ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:7f:05:19  
          inet addr:10.10.10.51  Bcast:10.10.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe7f:519/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:583 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:117 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:76518 (76.5 KB)  TX bytes:18000 (18.0 KB)
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0x2024 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:7f:05:23  
          inet addr:192.168.2.60  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe7f:523/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:631 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:59 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:85875 (85.8 KB)  TX bytes:8921 (8.9 KB)
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0x20a4 

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:7f:05:2d  
          inet addr:192.168.112.205  Bcast:192.168.112.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe7f:52d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:147 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:283 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:42615 (42.6 KB)  TX bytes:42952 (42.9 KB)
          Interrupt:16 Base address:0x2424 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:103 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:103 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:8632 (8.6 KB)  TX bytes:8632 (8.6 KB)
```

And heres my interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth2
iface eth2 inet dhcp

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.10.10.51
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.10.10.1

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.2.60
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.2.1
```

and here the error I'm having when runnign /etc/init.d/networking restart

```
root@ubuntu:/home/advitor# /etc/init.d/networking restart
 * Running /etc/init.d/networking restart is deprecated because it may not enable again some interfaces
 * Reconfiguring network interfaces...                                           * Disconnecting iSCSI targets
   ...done.
 * Stopping iSCSI initiator service
   ...done.
 * Starting iSCSI initiator service iscsid
   ...done.
 * Setting up iSCSI targets
   ...done.
ssh stop/waiting
ssh start/running, process 4394
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth0.
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth1.
```

I tried to run ifup -v to bring up more info regarding eth0 and eth1 and it gives me this.

```
root@ubuntu:/home/advitor# ifup -v eth1
Configuring interface eth1=eth1 (inet)
run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ethtool
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/vlan
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wireless-tools
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant
ip addr add 192.168.2.60/255.255.255.0 broadcast +    dev eth1 label eth1
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth1.

root@ubuntu:/home/advitor# ifup -v eth0
Configuring interface eth0=eth0 (inet)
run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ethtool
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/vlan
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wireless-tools
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant
ip addr add 10.10.10.51/255.255.255.0 broadcast +     dev eth0 label eth0
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth0.
```

I hope you could guide me how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is not recommended any more to use /etc/init.d/networking restart (as noted by your output). As explained [here](http://codeghar.wordpress.com/2011/07/18/debian-running-etcinit-dnetworking-restart-is-deprecated-because-it-may-not-enable-again-some-interfaces/), the preferred way is to manually bring down and up the interfaces.

Can you try this and see if it helps?

```
ifdown eth0
ifup eth0
ifdown eth1
ifup eth1
```

Comment: it gives me this error

Comment: root@ubuntu:/home/advitor# ifdown eth0
ifdown: interface eth0 not configured
root@ubuntu:/home/advitor# ifup eth0
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth0.